# livecode and mergext dropbox and 7.1 Simulator

Tags: livecode

I added the location of the .lcext file then tried to test on iOS

When trying the DropBox test app I get the following:

573,4,1,mergDropboxSetup
           253,3,1

I also get this:

1 Could not find appropriate build of external '/Users/sims/Desktop/MERG FILES/mergDropbox-1.0.5/mergDropbox.lcext' for Simulator-7_1

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of mergDropbox is 1.0.6 and was released on 24th March this year.
That version should work.

Comment: I used 1.0.6 of the external

Comment: I just did a quick test in LC 6.7.0dp2 with mergDropbox 1.0.6 using the sample stack (which is included with the external) in the Simulator 7.1. It works here. I do not get any error.

Comment: I was using LC 6.6.1 with mergDropBox 1.0.6 and the sample stack. Will have to see what LC version is useable i guess - i assume the "dp2" is developer preview so i would not want to use a dp for this project.

Comment: Thank you for you patience Matthias. After several tries to add the file in the app settings it now works. I need to sleep maybe :-P